# How sim800 get ssl certificate?

Tags: ssl, https

Sim800 supports SSL protocol. AT command "AT+CIPSSL" sets TCP to use SSL function.
In the "sim800_series_ssl_application_note_v1.01.pdf" is noted that: "Module will automatic **begin SSL certificate** after TCP connected." 
My Problem: What is the exact meaning of the **begin SSL certificate**? what does sim800 do exactly? Does sim800 get SSL certificate from website? where does sim800 save SSL certificate?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, SIM800 has some certificates in it and when you use a TCP+SSL or HTTP+SSL connection it will automatically use those certificates.

If those certificates are not ok for you, you will need to use an SD card, save there the certificates you want and use the command AT+SSLSETCERT to set the certificate you saved on your SD card. [Here](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2637/SIM800+Series_FS_Application+Note_V1.01.pdf) you can find how to use the File System.

Usually the certificates that come with the module are enough and you won't need this. But for example they didn't work for me when I tried to communicate with Azure via MQTT. I had to encrypt the data myself using wolfSSL library and send it using TCP without SSL.

Note: Not all SIM800 modules have SD card support.

Comment: could you elaborate on how you managed to communicate with Azure over TCP without SSL? I've tried various examples of this and the server rejects everytime :/

Answer (score 1):

There are a very few information about sim800 and ssl certificate on the web, and like you i got a lot of questions about it.

About your questions on how does sim800 get certificate and where does it save it, it seems, according to sim800_series_ssl_application_note_v1.01.pdf, that you can create (defining your own path), write and import a ssl certificate on your own with the AT+FSCREATE, AT+FSWRITE and AT+SSLSETCERT commands. An example is provided at the paragraph 3.10.

I'm sorry, i can't answer your other questions. 
Anyway, if you get further informations about sim800 and ssl, i would be grateful if you share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

When you use AT+CIPSSL you tell the SIM-module to use the SSL connection with TCP. When you use +CIPSTART command->

- SIM module requests the TCP connection with the server through SSL.
- Server sends the Server SSL certificate.
- The authenticity of that certificate is checked with internal certificate authority certificate (The one that resides inside SIM-module) which is cryptographically connected with server certificate.
- If the authenticity of certificate can not be confirmed SIM-module will close the connection unless you use the command AT+SSLOPT=0,0 (which forces the SIM-module to ignore invalid certificate authentication) prior to AT+CIPSSL command.

//Key exchange

- SIM-module then encrypts it's master key (already inside SIM-module cannot be changed or read) with the public key (Which is part of the already sent server certificate) and sends it back to server.
- Server then encrypts it's master key with SIM-module's master-key and sends it back to SIM-module. Key exchange is now complete as both (server and SIM-module) recieved master keys.

SIM-module currently doesn't support Client authentication which means that server cannot authenticate the client. That means there must be some other option of authentication (For example in MQTT that can be username and password that only client knows)

If you want your module to be able to authenticate server you will need to create the self-signed certificate for server and certificate authority certificate (for SIM-module) which is cryptographically connected to self-signed certificate and upload them to server and SIM-module (through AT+SSLSETCERT command from SD card).

If you only want to encrypt the data traffic you can ignore invalid certificate (AT+SSLOPT=0,0) as you will recieve publickey nevertheless. But if you want to be sure about server authenticity you will need to upload right certificate to module.